# Ambiguous reference CS0104: 'Debug' is an ambiguous reference between'UnityEngine.Debug' and 'System.Diagnostics.Debug'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging

I am new to programming and need help to fix error pop-up, which appeared after writing if statement in code, 5 error codes for all Debug.Log lines, before if statement they were working fine.

```
    int max = 1000;
    int min = 1;



    Debug.Log("Welcome to number Wizard");
    Debug.Log("Pick a number");
    Debug.Log("Highest number is: " + max);
    Debug.Log("Lowest number is: " + min);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        Debug.Log("Up Arrow key was pressed");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't need it on top of your file remove the

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

---

Otherwise either use the full namespace

```
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("some text");
```

or add

```
using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;
```

at the top of your file.